# How to restrict number of hits to S3 bucket via presigned URL?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

I Want to restrict the number of S3 operation via pre-signed URL.  Currently I can have expiry time. Same way can we specify number of hits?

I am using below node JS code to get pre-signed URL. I am geting the signed URL

```
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
      Bucket: myBucket,
      Key: myKey,
      Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently there is no way to restrict number of hits on a presigned URL. You can change the expiry time. You should contact AWS support and request this feature though, it does sound useful.